# Android - differentiating between configuration changes

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I am trying to make a sample app that performs an action only on a Locale change. I have implmented onConfigurationChanged(...) and would like to redirect a user to a different Activity only on a Locale change. The Activity that listens to Locale changes also listens to orientation changes (which I've done in the manifest).

My question is, is there any way to differentiate between the two configuration changes ?

The Activity is declared in the manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name=".views.MainActivity"
              android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

And the onConfigurationChange(..) method is like so:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // should execute only on locale change
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your locale in your SharedPreferences and compare in the onConfigurationChanged method if the locale has changed.

Use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
  "yourapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.getString("locale", "DEFAULT"); 

    //newConfig.locale is deprecated since API lvl 24, you can also use newConfig.getLocales().get(0) 
    if(!locale.equalsIgnoreCase(newConfig.locale.toLanguageTag()) {
        // should execute only on locale change
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("yourapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString("locale", newConfig.locale.toLanguageTag());
        prefEditor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, you could avoid using SharedPreferences by storing a reference to the previous Locale in onCreate (the first time the Activity loads before any locale changes happen) and then compare the two locales.

Comment: Of course, that makes it even more simple. Didn't think of that, but I'm glad i could help :)